# nLog doesnt fire webservice method

Tags: c#, nlog

I've been following an example on the nlog projects homepage, but I can't get it to work. The example can be found at: http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_WebServiceTarget.htm

The problem occurs when using the nLog targets. My config:

```
<targets>
    <target name="ws" xsi:type="WebService" namespace="http://www.nlog-project.org/example" protocol="Soap11" methodName="HelloWorld" url="http://localhost:53810/Service1.asmx">
        <parameter name="n1" type="System.String" layout="${message}"/>
        <parameter name="n2" type="System.String" layout="${logger}"/>
        <parameter name="n3" type="System.String" layout="${level}"/>           
    </target>       
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="test" writeTo="ws" />     
</rules>
```

When I start the console app nothing happens, BUT if I change my URL to the following it seems to trigger the method:

```
http://localhost:53810/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld
```

But when using this method parameters don't seem to work..

My webservice method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void HelloWorld(string n1, string n2, string n3)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("n1 " + n1);
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("n2 " + n2);
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("n3 " + n3);
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I've tried with both HttpPost and Soap11.

Comment: The wiki page for the [WebService Target](http://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target) in the remarks section says that the webservice must accept a method which handles query string parameters, do you web service accepts these? How are the web service created?

Comment: @Xharze See my edit. My method is the same as the example. The webservice is an regular ASP.NET Web Serice Application.

Comment: Can you verified the querystring is actually genereated? Just to make sure if this is a NLog problem or webservice problem?

Comment: Hmm, how should I do that? I've tried Fiddler but it doesnt show up there..

Comment: I found the problem! The namespace wasn't the same. When I changed it everything worked as expected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The namespace of in the nlog config file needs to be exactly the same as the namespace of the webservice.

nlog config:

```
namespace="http://tempuri.org/"
```

webservice:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```